macOS NSOpenPanel use symlink for directoryURL
I am trying to open the NSOpenPanel at /opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg.
Directory should be /opt/homebrew/bin/ and ffmpeg should be highlighted.
However, the NSOpenPanel seems to always resolve the symlink and shows this path instead: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/7.0.2/bin/ffmpeg.
I already tried resolveAliases = false. I also tried just setting it to the parent directory, but I would love for the symlink to be highlighted.
This is a sample application to reproduce the issue:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Button("Show details") {
                openDialog()
            }
                
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func openDialog() {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()

    // The path to the symlink
    let symlinkPath = "/opt/homebrew/bin/ffmpeg"

    // Convert to NSURL and create a custom scheme URL
    var symlinkURL = URL(filePath: symlinkPath)
    
    openPanel.resolvesAliases = false
    
    // Set the directoryURL to the folder instead of the symlink
    // openPanel.directoryURL = symlinkURL.deletingLastPathComponent()

    // Set the directoryURL to the symlink resolves the symlink, even if resolve aliases is false
    openPanel.directoryURL = symlinkURL

    // Configure the open panel as needed
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = true
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
    openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false

    // Present the open panel
    if openPanel.runModal() == .OK {
        if let selectedURL = openPanel.url {
            print("Selected file: \(selectedURL.path)")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


resolveAliases resolves the selected aliases/symlinks. NSOpenPanel doesn't show a path, it shows the item represented by the URL.

From directoryURL in NSSavePanel.h : "NSSavePanel/NSOpenPanel: Gets and sets the directoryURL shown. A value of nil indicates that the last directory shown to the user will be used. This method will not block to resolve the URL, and the directory will asyncronously be set, if required."

@Willeke thanks for the clarifications. So according to the documentation it is not possible to show an unresolved symlink as the initially selected file?
